# Windows Universal App: SelectedItem with GridView and grouped Datasource

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an application where the user must select a color. Either a theme color or a custom color. Because they have different values I have an interface IColor and an implementation for a Custom Color (ValueColor) like this:

```
public sealed class ValueColor : INodeColor, IEquatable<ValueColor>
{
    private readonly int color;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as ValueColor);
    }

    public bool Equals(INodeColor other)
    {
        return Equals(other as ValueColor);
    }

    public bool Equals(ValueColor other)
    {
        return other != null && other.color == color;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return color.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

To show the colors I use a GridView and bind this to a list of color groups:

```
public class Group
{
    public List<INodeColor> Items { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I noticed the following:

```
// Works:
GroupedList.SelectedItem = Groups[0].Items[5]; // = new ValueColor(16);

// Works not:
GroupedList.SelectedItem = new ValueColor(16);
```

The GridView falls back to a reference comparison when grouping is enabled, when I ensure that there is only one reference for each color, everything works fine. I could cache it in this scenario but I also have another situations where it is not possible.

Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: When you are grouping might be override bool Equals(object obj) that obj is not always a ValueColor but a group object?

Comment: I did, see the "as" operator.

Comment: I don't know if this is by design or not, but I have always assumed that it is. Why is it so difficult to use reference equality? After all, if you do `GroupedList.SelectedItem = new ValueColor(16);`, you assume there is a ValueColor in the list with the value 16, right? How do you know? Just set SelectedItem to the one that is already in there.

Comment: Because it makes everything more complicated. I have several scenarios like this with a lot data. When I dont want to end in a memory leak I have to think about cache contexts. When such a context changes I also need to fill my lists again and so on. It is just something that should work I think.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a "cache" or if you did have one, why it's lifetime would be difficult to manage. Your data source is all the "cache" you need, no? And if you do have a separate collection, its lifetime can be linked to the lifetime of the gridview. Why is that complicated?

Comment: When I need the same references I need something like an infinite lifetime cache, isnt it? ;)